# How can I localize string inside function?

Tags: wordpress, localization

I'm having some problems figuring out how to localize the string this function returns. What is the correct way of making strings translatable inside a function?

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);
function add_search_box_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'mobile' )
        return $items."<li class='menu-header-search'><form id='searchform' method='get'><input type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='This placeholder text should be translatable'></form></li>";

    return $items;
}
```

This is the method which I initially thought would work, but didn't:

```
<li class='menu-header-search'><form id='searchform' method='get'><input type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='" . __('This placeholder text should be translatable', 'my_textdomain') . "'></form></li>";
```

Comment: how do you handle the returned value? when you say it's not wokring? what does it do? what is the result vs the expected result?

Comment: The returned value creates a searchbox in my mobile navigation which displays perfectly. The problem is that the WPML plugin is not finding the string.

Comment: WPML is not finding the string means it returns the exact string as the one you pass to the __() function right?

Comment: Yes, it returns the searchbox with the correct default placeholder.

Comment: Where do you have the above code block? in functions.php? or in a plugin? if it's in functions.php you need to replace "my_textdomain" with the themes text domain so where is it?

Comment: It's in the functions.php file, but it is originally with the right textdomain. I just changed it when I wrote the question so it would be easier to read.

Comment: is the first variable: "This placeholder text should be translatable" in the theme's translation file? get a string that gets translated instead of the placeholder you have now and check the result if it gets translated then it's something wrong with the placeholder text, if not let us know and we'll keep debuging...

Comment: It's not in the translation file. I tried changing the `<li class='menu-he...` line with `__('some text here', 'wilfa');` and that didn't show up either..

Comment: instead of "some text here" add a text that is translated somewere in the theme like "title" and see if it gets translated...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) to translate strings, even in functions. Your code would look like this:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);
function add_search_box_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'mobile' )
        return $items."<li class='menu-header-search'><form id='searchform' method='get'><input type='text' name='s' id='s' placeholder='".__('This placeholder text should be translatable')."'></form></li>";

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: this is excactly the same code as I wrote as the method that didn't work... Am I not getting something here..? :S

Comment: This is the part that changed: `placeholder='".__('This placeholder text should be translatable')."'` Once you do this you can translate your text using your multilingual plugin or your .po files.

Comment: without the textdomain? As you can see from my question I have one line of code underneath the first codeblock where I basically tried the excact same thing you typed: `placeholder='".__('This placeholder text should be translatable', 'my_textdomain')."'`. However, I also tried copying this excactly and with the same results.. :/

Comment: This should work, and yes, you can add a text domain too. Is the function returning your html correctly? Maybe the problem is with the translation files.

Comment: I find it weird as well.. The html is working just fine, it displays correctly, but I can't find the string when searching for it with the WPML plugin. I'm using this button to research for strings [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/7Qdx2wv.png)

Comment: Are you using the right text domain? Is this text domain working with other strings? Where is your filter function (theme files, custom plugin...)? Thx

Comment: I've used this textdomain with 70 strings this far. All of them working fine, it's just this particular one inside functions.php that eludes me :)

Comment: Have you tried to put the translated text in a variable at the start of the function and then use it in your return statement? (`$myText = __('...');`)